# Replacing iAds (canDisplayBannerAds) with Admob

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iad

I am changing from iAds (canDisplayBannerAds) to Admob. canDisplayBannerAds would move up the bottomLayoutGuide so that all the constraints followed and iAds just sat beneath. I am adding Admob with the GADMasterViewController. Is there a way to programmatically move the bottomLayoutGuide to make room for the ad bar beneath?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do all the view controllers by connecting the bottomlayoutguide constraint in IB as an outlet (_bottomConstraint) and then using this code where adView.adHeight is the height of the adBanner.

```
[[GADMasterViewController singleton] resetAdView:self];

GADMasterViewController *adView = [[GADMasterViewController alloc] init];
[_toolbar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
_bottomConstraint.constant = [adView.adHeight floatValue];
```

I have not figured out a solution for table view controllers short of reading about replacing them with a view controller with an table subview. which I would rather avoid.